# The set of all sequences of complex numbers with limit $0$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, they set an example for a subspace:

*The set of all sequences of complex numbers with limit 0 is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$*,

where $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ denotes the vector space of complex sequences over $\mathbb{C}$.

How can I interpret the ¨with limit 0¨ part? does it mean, looking at an element of the subspace as a function f(z), that

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_o} f(z) = 0$$ ?

How can we go on about to prove sub set of functions is a subspace?

Comment: You're probably looking at the set $\{(z_n)_{n=0}^\infty: \lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=0\}$. You want to show that this is a subspace of $\{(z_n)_{n=0}^\infty: \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |z_n|<\infty\}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's put a name to our reputed subspace, say $U$. Then $U$ is the set of all complex sequences $(z_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_{n} = 0. $$
Let us now prove that $U$ is a subspace.

1. Remember that the additive identity of our vector space $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ is the sequence whose terms are all zero: $(0, 0, 0, 0, \dots)$. It is indeed the case that the limit of this sequence is $0$, so it belongs to $U$.
2. Now take two sequences $(z_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(w_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ in $U$. Then
   $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (z_{n} + w_{n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_{n} + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} w_{n} = 0 + 0 = 0, $$
   so the sequence $(z_{n} + w_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is in $U$. This shows that $U$ is closed under addition.
3. Now let $\lambda$ be an arbitrary complex number. We see that
   $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda z_{n} = \lambda \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_{n} = \lambda \cdot 0 = 0, $$
   so the sequence $(\lambda z_{n})_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is in $U$. This shows that $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

We can therefore conclude that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure how to write down the proof but this clears it up.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it says $\ell^\infty$, which is the set of bounded sequences. So you want to show that
$$
c_0^{\vphantom0}=\{f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C:\ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0\}
$$
is a subspace of
$$
\ell^\infty=\{f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C:\ \|f\|_\infty<\infty\}.
$$
Same effort to show that $c_0$ is a subspace of $\mathbb C^\infty$.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ a problem?

Comment: It isn't. It's just less common (at least in Functional Analysis) because you cannot put a norm to it.

Comment: Im sorry what does $||f||_{\infty}$ means? Im just starting on this book and this notation is a bit out of what ive ever seen

Comment: Usually, $$\|f\|_\infty=\sup\{|f(t):\ t\}.$$ In measure theory things are slightly more complicated, but the spirit is the same.